# How to set select list value in angular 4 by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on angular 4 application.

I have requirement of setting select list value from my typescript file by using javascript.

HTML code

```
<select id="hours">
   <option value=1>1</option>
   <option value=2>2</option>
   <option value=3>3</option>
    .....
</select>
<select id="minutes">
   <option value=1>1</option>
   <option value=2>2</option>
   <option value=3>3</option>
   .....
</select>
```

TYPESCRIPT

```
time : any;
constructor{
   this.time = 130;
}
ngOnInit {
   this.setValue();
}

setValue()
{
   let time = this.time;
   let hours = Math.floor(time/60);
   let minutes = time%60;
}
```

I have split time into hours and minutes. Now I just want to set hours in hours dropdown and minutes in minutes dropdown.

Comment: read some tutorial about  ng-model and forms on the net, you will learn how to handle properly forms.

Comment: I know what you want to say but I don't want to use forms or ng-model. I need to do this with javascript.

Comment: Then I think it may be really better that you drop angular and use native typescript, angular is made to handle the manipulation of the DOM for you. You're shooting yourself in the foot by trying to workaround the basics of the framework while using it.